# Simplify $\log((10\cdot 8 )^{\frac{1}{2}} \times (0.24)^{\frac{5}{3}} \div (90)^{-2})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

> Simplify $\log((10\cdot 8 )^{\frac{1}{2}} \times (0.24)^{\frac{5}{3}} \div (90)^{-2})$

$\Rightarrow \log(10\cdot 8)^{\frac{1}{2}}+\log(0.24)^{\frac{5}{3}}-\log(90)^{-2} \tag{1}$

$\Rightarrow \dfrac{1}{2}(\log10+3\log2)+\dfrac{5}{3}(\log(\dfrac{6}{25}))+2\log(2\cdot5\cdot3^2) \tag{2}$

$\Rightarrow \dfrac{1}{2}(1+3\log2)+\dfrac{5}{3}(\log2+\log3-2\log5)+2(\log2+\log5+2\log3) \tag{3}$

$\Rightarrow \dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{3}{2}\log2+\dfrac{5}{3}\log2+\dfrac{5}{3}\log3-\dfrac{10}{3}\log5+2\log2+2\log5+4\log3 \tag{4}$

$\Rightarrow \dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{31}{6}\log2+\dfrac{17}{3}\log3-\dfrac{4}{3}\log5 \tag{5}$

$\Rightarrow \dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{31}{6}\log2+\dfrac{17}{3}\log3-\dfrac{4}{3}(1-\log2) \tag{6}$

$\Rightarrow -\dfrac{5}{6}+\dfrac{39}{6}\log2+\dfrac{17}{3}\log3 \tag{7}$

But the answer is given as $-\dfrac{11}{6}+6\log2+\dfrac{43}{6}\log3$. My calculations look all good to me, but clearly somewhere it is wrong. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I pored over your working; nothing seems amiss. I tried verifying the answer with Wolfram Alpha, but their symbolic manipulations of logarithms is seemingly non-existent, so the answer changed subtly with each step. [This was about the best confirmation I could get it to come up with.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=10%5E%7B-5%2F6%7D+*+2%5E%7B13%2F2%7D+*+3%5E%7B17%2F3%7D+-+sqrt%2880%29+*+0.24%5E%285%2F3%29+%2F+%2890%29%5E%28-2%29) I just raised your answer and the original problem to the power of $10$, then subtracted. Note the difference is very small, probably within machine epsilon.

Comment: Is that $10 \cdot 8$ (which would be $80$) or $10.8$ (which would be $10\frac 45$)? I haven't proofed what the answer to either would be or whether you have an error though.  You don't seem to have any errors in your conceptualizing though.  Going over with a fine tooth comb may be worth while.  Or it might just be fine to shrug, quit, and move on to the next problem. (errors do occur.)

Comment: I think [you cracked this one wide open](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=10%5E%7B-11%2F6%7D+*+2%5E%7B6%7D+*+3%5E%7B43%2F6%7D+-+sqrt%2810.8%29+*+0.24%5E%285%2F3%29+%2F+%2890%29%5E%28-2%29), @fleablood.

Comment: @TheoBendit  Did you do the work?  It occurs to me that $10.8 = \frac {54}5$ fit into this excercise breaking down into linear combinations $\log_{10} 2$ and $\log_{10}3$ (That is $\log 10.8^{\frac 12} = \frac 12(\log 54 - \log 5)= \frac 12(\log 2\cdot 3^3 -\log 10 + \log 2)=..... $) but I didn't actually bother proofing *anything*.

Comment: @fleablood No, I didn't do the work either. I was just pointing out that Wolfram Alpha's numerical evaluations make them very close to each other, which makes it a promising lead.

Comment: I did the work.   It works.  (Assuming both the OP and the text did their work correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's $10.8$ (i.e. $10 \frac 45$) rather than $10\cdot 8$ (i.e $80$)

You'd get $\log_{10} 10.8^{\frac 12} = \frac 12(\frac {4\cdot 3^3}{10})=\frac 12(2\log 2 + 3\log 3 - 1)= \log 2 + \frac 32 \log 3 - \frac 12$

rather than $\log 80^{\frac 12} =\frac 12( \log 8\cdot 10) = \frac 32\log 2 + \frac 12$

If so your answer is off by $-\frac 12\log 2 +\frac 32\log 3 - 1$.

Add that to your answer and you get $[-\dfrac{5}{6}+\dfrac{39}{6}\log2+\dfrac{17}{3}\log3] + [ -\frac 12\log 2 +\frac 32\log 3 - 1]=$
$-\frac {11}6 + 6\log 2 +\frac {43}6\log 3$  which is the texts answer.

So that's that, I presume.  You interpreted a decimal point as a times sign.  (And had a lot more patience and lack of errors than I ever could manage.)